# Accuracy of distance and bearing between GPS locations

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

I'm writing on an Android app that tracks the distance and bearing between two GPS location (each from a different device).

Finding the mean distance and angle between the devices is quite easy, and seems to work well. 
But since my locations are rather close, and I really need the results to be as reliable as possible, I'm also trying calculating the **uncertainty** of the calculations, and here I need some help.

I'm using the accuracy parameter I get from android as my error estimation for the GPS readings (Android docs say this parameter gives a circular radius that the location has a 68% certainty to be within, so I assume the result is normally distributed, and that this parameter is the SD).

I know how to officially calculate the propagated uncertainty (using partial derivatives) if I ignore the covariance (which I have no idea if I could even theoretically find) - But this gives me a **tremendous** uncertainty, since both GPS readings have a very large uncertainty.

The thing is, all I'm looking for is the **relative** distance (or angle) between these location, and I don't care where they really are compared to earth. And since I know that at lest some of this uncertainty is the same for both devices (for instance, Ionospheric effects), I could safely ignore them and get much more precise results.
Even better, if part of the uncertainty comes from random errors, I could filter most of it out even before comparing the locations (Although I suspect that that the location Android provides is already filtered).

The thing is, I don't know what part of the uncertainty is random and what part is constant, and I obviously have to deal with them separately...

So, to sum up my problem - given two sets of GPS reading, plus their *'accuracy'*, how can I tell apart the uncertainty that is the same for both sets, from the part the varies between them?
I'm sure there is a good mathematical way to do this, I just can't think of one...

Comment: I believe you need a 3rd device whose location is known.

Comment: Perhaps, you can use the nearest cell-tower location to reduce the uncertainty.

Comment: Actually, a third device with an exact known location would help pin the other location to the map, but I need much less than that. All I need is a way to tell apart the relative error from the rest, and ignoring that part should drastically improve my results.